# C# MySQL in multithreaded application

Tags: c#, mysql, multithreading

I've developed an emulation program for a game. The program works with MySQL for database communication. I have tried to use the IDisposable method (which is suggested mostly by everyone), to allocate a MySQL connection to a thread, when that specific thread requires something to do with the database. However, when the server reaches over 400 users, the MySQL server gets overloaded with requests. I have also tried the pooling option (size: min 0, max. 150) - it resulted the same issue.

Currently, I am using locking to provide a parallelism system. The system works with static objects (static connection object) to manage the whole server (I think it affects the performance offered by multithreading though).

```
public static Boolean Query(ref MySqlDataReader Resource, String Query)
{
    lock (Connection)
    {
        MySqlCommand Cmd = new MySqlCommand(Query, Connection);

        try
        {
            Resource = Cmd.ExecuteReader();
        }
        catch (MySqlException Exception)
        {
             Console.WriteLine("MySQL Error: " + Exception.Message);
             return false;
        }

        return true;
    }
}
```

A method that works with the "Query" method.

```
public static String GetObjectProperty(
                 String Field, String Identifier, 
                 Boolean Primary = true, String Table = "Accounts")
{
    String FieldValue = null;
    try
    {
        lock (GeneralDB.Connection)
        {
            MySqlDataReader DataReader = null;
            if (GeneralDB.Query(
                          ref DataReader, 
                          "SELECT " + MySqlHelper.EscapeString(Field) + 
                          " FROM " + Table + 
                          " WHERE " + (Primary ? "ID" : "Name") + " = '" + 
                          MySqlHelper.EscapeString(Identifier) + "';") == false)
            {
                return null;
            }
            if (DataReader == null) return null;
            while (DataReader.Read()) 
                FieldValue = DataReader[0].ToString();
            DataReader.Close();
            return FieldValue;
        }
    }

    catch (Exception Exception)
    {
        return FieldValue;
    }
}
```

I desperately need some suggestions. Thanks.

Comment: Suggestions for what? You haven't asked a question..

Comment: The only suggestion I could make which isnt really an answer is find a way to select data for multiple users based on their proximity (assuming I am reading this right) from the objects in question and then "pasting" the data back to the connections. Unless of course this is not a client/server application but a client/mysql application

Comment: No, this is a client-server application.